# How can I do a jquery post for a file upload form?

Tags: jquery, serialization, file-upload, coldfusion

I have a form that looks something like this:

```
<form id="uploadForm" name="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="uploadFile" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="process" name="process" value="Process File" />
</form>
```

I want to allow the user to upload a file, and then process it. When the user hits "process" I want to call this page using a jquery post (this form is being shown in a cfwindow, and I don't want to leave the cfwindow), do some processing and output a message. This is the code I would usually use:

```
$('#process').click(function(){
    $.post('<cfoutput>#cgi.script_name#</cfoutput>', $('#uploadForm').serialize(), function(data){
        ... some processing ...
    });
});
```

However, nothing is being passed. Further investigation led me to the jquery documentation for the [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function, which states:

> Data from file select elements is not serialized.

How can I pass the file select element?

(If this makes a difference - when I post to the page I'm using this code to read the file that is uploaded in the file select element:

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#form.uploadFile#" sheet="1" query="spreadsheetData" headerRow="1" excludeHeaderRow="true">
```

Originally I was just using the regular form post and it was working perfectly. I'd like to switch over to ajax so that I can keep the cfwindow open instead of reloading.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [Valums File Uploader](http://github.com/valums/file-uploader) project. It allows for upload through XHR like you're trying to do. You can use his library or adapt his concept to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks! I think I may try using the jquery form plugin instead... http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started

Comment: I ended up using the jquery form plugin, but I'm going to accept this answer because I could have used yours just as easily, and it led me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way around this is to have the form target a hidden iFrame:

```
<!-- fileupload.cfm -->
<script>function functionToHandleUploadComplete(){ // Do things here }</script>
<form action="getfile.cfm" method="post" target="myHiddeniFrame" />
  <input type="file" name="myFile" />
  <!-- your fields -->  
</form>

<iframe id="myHiddeniFrame" style="somthing to hide the frame" />

<!-- getFile.cfm loaded in an iFrame within fileUpload.cfm-->
<cffile action="upload" formField="myFile" ..... />
<cfoutput>
  <script>
    window.parent.functionToHandleUploadComplete();
  </script>
</cfoutput>
```

We use this approach in our product and it works fine. Providing the page you sending to is on the same domain, you can have it push out javascript to tell the containing page that the upload has completed.

I'd take a look at the File Uploader project first though, as it looks rather nifty.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this - where do I put the code to handle my processing?

Comment: Yeah, the answer was a little too brief, hopefully its slightly clearer now